# Google Ads — Can't create new campaign, when I click "Continue" nothing happens

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

Create new Campaign

Website Traffic > Search > enter link & company name > Click "Continue"...

*Results:*

- nothing happens. the interface does not change or give any feedback.

Click "Continue" again

- nothing happens. the interface does not change or give any feedback.

click "Continue" a 3rd time, you are taken back to the Campaigns screen and your new campaign is not created.

Expected result:

- The campaign is created correctly

*Question: Google Ads- how can this be resolved so that I can create new campaigns?*

[image]

Comment: Whenever the Google Ads manager interface through the browser goes wonky (which it does far more often than Google would like to admit), I always use the [Google Ads Editor](https://ads.google.com/intl/en_uk/home/tools/ads-editor/) app. Even when the browser interface is completely unavailable or unresponsive, it always works.